# R: Inconsistent behavior in `match` with lists

Tags: r, match

`match` is giving inconsistent results when working with list objects:

```
match(list(c(1, 2)), list(c(1L, 2L)))
#> [1] NA
match(list(c(1, 3)), list(c(1L, 3L)))
#> [1] 1
```

What is going on under the hood in `match` to cause this?

It's not simply the difference between `integer` and `numeric`:

```
match(c(1, 2), c(1L, 2L))
#> [1] 1 2
match(c(1, 3), c(1L, 3L))
#> [1] 1 2
```

Some additional examples. The behavior seems to surface only with sequential values:

```
match(list(c(100, 101, 102)), list(c(100L, 101L, 102L)))
#> [1] NA
match(list(c(100, 102, 101)), list(c(100L, 102L, 101L)))
#> [1] 1
match(list(c(2, 1)), list(c(2L, 1L)))
#> [1] NA
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is 1,2 are *consecutive integers*.

In the detail section in `?match`, it mentions:

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex < character) before matching. If incomparables has positive length it is coerced to the common type.

For consecutive integer numbers, they are parsed as `starting number: ending number`

```
as.character(list(c(1L,2L)))
[1] "1:2"

as.character(list(c(100L, 101L, 102L)))
[1] "100:102"
```

Where as the other:

```
as.character(list(c(1L,3L)))
[1] "c(1, 3)"

as.character(list(c(1,2)))
[1] "c(1, 2)"
```

Comment: Yes, this makes sense that `match` is converting the list objects to character objects before comparison. I didn't realize the conversion would use colon notation, but that also makes sense. Thank you!